# Grails spring security core 3.1.2 and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, grails, spring-security, grails-orm

I have been using spring-security-ccore 3.1.1 a while. I decided to update to 3.1.2, but I found some problems working together with mongodb database.

Since the password encoding is not directly in domain class
[image]

I'm using mongoDB as primary database, so I commented all hibernate plugins.
[image]

This is the error.
[image]

Is it missing something? I know the bean name is 'hibernateDatastore', but I did not find any documentation relate about mongodb and spring security.

Should I use the password encoding directly in domain class?

[image]

User.groovy (With mongodb modifications)

[image]

application.yml

[image]

gradle.properties

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/issues/496

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a simple app with Spring Security Core and MongoDB:

https://github.com/grails-spring-security-samples/grails-ssc-mongodb

You need to modify slightly the output of s2-quickstart

You would need to replace in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`

```
userPasswordEncoderListener(UserPasswordEncoderListener, ref('hibernateDatastore'))
```

with:

```
userPasswordEncoderListener(UserPasswordEncoderListener, ref('mongoDatastore'))
```